# How to forbid equal indexes in QComboBoxes

Tags: qt

I have got a number of `QComboBox`es. Suppose that we have one `combobox` with index `i` and another `combobox` with index `j`. If user activate index `j` in the first `combobox` I want the second `combobox` index to be changed to `i`, so that there no equal indexes in all `comboboxes`. What is the easiest way to do it? I have tryed to do it with `SIGNALS AND SLOTS` approach:

```
    for(int i=0;i<boxes.size();++i){
    connect(boxes[i], SIGNAL(activated(int)),this,SLOT(boxIndexChanged(int)));
}
```

where `boxes` is a `QList<QComboBox*>` the problem here is that i don't know in `slot` function `boxIndexChanged(int index)` which `combobox` have emited signal(I need it in the case if there are identical indexes in two `combobox`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have at least two options:

- Use [QObject::sender()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qobject.html#sender) to get a pointer to object which emitted a signal. Please note, that it's a simple, but not recommended way (see method's documentation).
- Use [QSignalMapper](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qsignalmapper.html).